# How do I centre a button on top of a flashing background?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my 'Click here' button to sit on top of the flashing background. I need the button to be clickable, but it doesn't format properly (must sit centre) when I stick it on top of the background images. The way I have it formatted now means I can see it, but it is not clickable. This is what I have so far:

```css
#bg {
  padding: 16em 0 13em 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  line-height: 1.75;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431352832634-845fad190fbd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=ec80c41e488dc2b99ed543df2f3f0919");
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: cover;
  line-height: 1.75;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -2;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(3);
  filter: brightness(3);
  -o-filter: brightness(3);
  -moz-filter: brightness(3);
}
.flashit {
  -webkit-animation: flash ease-out 10s infinite;
  -moz-animation: flash ease-out 10s infinite;
  animation: flash ease-out 10s infinite;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  93% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  94% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  96% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes flash {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  93% {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  94% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  96% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.bg-lighted {
  padding: 16em 0 13em 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  line-height: 1.75;
  text-align: center;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431352832634-845fad190fbd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=ec80c41e488dc2b99ed543df2f3f0919');
  background-position: center center;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(3);
  filter: brightness(3);
  -o-filter: brightness(3);
  -moz-filter: brightness(3);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">

  <p>TEST TEXT</p>
  <ul class="actions">
    <li><a href="#" class="button special big">Click here</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="bg-lighted flashit"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ul.actions {
       list-style: none;
       padding: 0;
    }
```

ul has a default padding, you need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a fiddle with it.
I don't exactly know what your flash transition is supposed to do or how you insert it in your page but see if this is what you're looking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/virginieLGB/2wh4r1d5/1/

I've changed the order of the divs by placing div.bg-lighted inside #bg, and set its position to absolute.

```
<div id="bg">
  <p>TEST TEXT</p>
  <ul class="actions">
    <li><a href="#" class="button special big">Click here</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="bg-lighted flashit"></div>
</div>
```

I've also cleaned the ul.actions look, as also suggested by João Vilaça:

```
ul.actions {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```